# Character substitution in question title?

Tags: bug, title

I just noticed this question, which should have a "--" in the title. Viewing the page source, it appears to have been replaced with `&mdash;`. It showed that way on the "active" page too. In the context of a C++ question, the difference is significant.

[Overload of operator-- (prefix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907161/overload-of-operator-prefix)

I didn't think Markdown was applied to titles, so what's going on?

Comment: @Servy then it's done incorrectly. It should be translated to two entities.